# Cannot boot into Ubuntu :: I get the screen with the loding bar and then static

Tags: ubuntu

How can I boot into Ubuntu and fix this? I get the loading bar then the equivalent of TV static. How can I get GNOME working again? GRUB is working normally and I can still boot into vista.

Comment: Is this a Virtual Machine?  If not, can you give us more information about the hardware -- specifically the graphics adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your Xorg server configuration - dump into command line and check your Xorg logs. It should provide strong clues on where the problem lie.

To dump into command line from the static screen, you can try pressing CTRL-ALT-BACKSPACE.

**EDIT : CTRL-ALT-BACKSPACE was to terminate X server, not Xorg. New procedures updated below.**

1. Press CTRL-ALT-F1
2. Login
3. type *sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop* to stop the Xorg server

Comment: FYI that may have changed recently. RightALT-Printscreen-K is the combination for killing X for more recent versions. But for me it just restarts X, and doesn't kick me out into the command line.

Comment: Try CTRL-ALT-F1?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue when installing on some machines.  If choosing F4 : "Safer Graphics Mode" fixes the issue when booting from the Ubuntu CD then try setting the VESA video mode in your grub configuration /boot/grub/menu.lst file.  Details on boot options can be found here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Short answer: add vga=771 to the boot line.  You can test this by choosing the Edit option when the grub menu appears.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say scan the RAM .   The Ubuntu boot disk has a scanner on it I think.